# ILO2 scheduled startup/shutdown

Tags: hp, ilo

I recently just bought a server a hp ml350 g5. And i uses a lot of power. So i was wondering is there anyway to schedule it turn it off and on via the ilo2. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you really want it to fail earlier by stressing it at bootup and shutdown? It's a business decision.

Answer (score 0):

Weird question. I'm assuming this is for a home setup... The ILO itself doesn't have a scheduler for this built-in. Most people who run servers tend to want them to stay on.

(*the HP ProLiant ML350 G5 dates back to 2005-2008. It's very much end-of-life...*)

You can:

- Turn the server off via its operating system.
- You have options to wake-on-lan with this equipment, but again, it seems silly since you could just remote into the system and power it on.
- You can issue commands to the ILO to power-on and power-off, but if you go through that effort, you may as well just cleanly shut the server off via its OS.

What is the core issue you're trying to resolve?